# One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'publish:end:remote' event

Tags: publishing, events, sxa-jss

I recently started seeing errors on my headless SXA CM instance every time a publish operation is performed:

```
One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'publish:end:remote' event.
Exception[1]: System.InvalidOperationException 
Message[1]: Invalid event arg type: Sitecore.Data.Events.PublishEndRemoteEventArgs. Expected: SitecoreEventArgs 
Source[1]: Sitecore.Kernel 
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.ExtractParameters(EventArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.ExtractParameter(EventArgs args, Int32 index)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.EventHandlers.SiteCacheClearer.OnPublishEnd(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
```

I have isolated the issue to a custom JSS webhook that calls the Vercel API (this configuration is modelled after the pattern described in this post: https://miguelminoldo.fr/2021/10/18/deploying-sitecore-jss-next-vercel/

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:search="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/search/">
  <sitecore>
    <javaScriptServices>
      <publishWebHooks type="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices.WebHooks.WebHooks, Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices">
        <hooks hint="list:AddWebHook">
          <hook type="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices.WebHooks.WebHookDefinition, Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices">
            <name>Vercel - Publish Hook</name>
            <url>https://api.vercel.com/v1/integrations/deploy/prj_xxxxxxxx</url>
            <method>POST</method>
            <site>sitecoreverceldemo</site>
            <body></body>
          </hook>
        </hooks>
      </publishWebHooks>
    </javaScriptServices>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

When I manually make a `POST` request to that endpoint, I get a valid response with a `201` response code. The response body is:

```json
{"job":{"id":"xxxxxxx","state":"PENDING","createdAt":1711646911282}}
```

It is unclear what the implications are of this error, and it is also unclear why the error is firing in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This error message looks strange, it says that Sitecore calls an incorrect event handler method for the `publish:end:remote` event.

Please check your generated Sitecore config from `/sitecore/admin/shownconfig.aspx` and search for *Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.EventHandlers.SiteCacheClearer*, it should be configured as follows:

```
<events>
   <event name="publish:end">
      <handler type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.EventHandlers.SiteCacheClearer, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite" method="OnPublishEnd" />
      ...
   </event>
   <event name="publish:end:remote">
      <handler type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.EventHandlers.SiteCacheClearer, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite" method="OnPublishEndRemote" />
      ...
   </event>
   ...
</events>
```

Event handlers for `publish:end` and `publish:end:remote` should call different methods because they accept different argument types:

- `publish:end` works with `Sitecore.Events.SitecoreEventArgs`
- `publish:end:remote` works with `Sitecore.Data.Events.PublishEndRemoteEventArgs`

From the error message and stack trace it looks like the `publish:end:remote` event calls the method `OnPublishEnd` instead of `OnPublishEndRemote`, therefore it is unable to extract event arguments from the type `PublishEndRemoteEventArgs` because it expects to receive `SitecoreEventArgs`.